# Photoshop - How to apply gradient to only part of an image in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I am trying to create a wallpaper with a white background, and a kind of floating picture/portrait of Robert Heinlein. I have the picture edited down to the parts I want, but its not white, so I want to apply a surrounding gradient to the image (see below) so that it fades, all around, into the white wallpaper background. Whenever I try to do this however, I can only manage to apply the gradient to the entire image--Is there a way to apply it only to the parts of the image I want? i.e. start at pure white at the edge, and then fade, but only to a certain point into the existing photo?

[image: Heinlein]

Comment: You need to separate him from the background. I'd use Pen tool and draw a path all around him and then right click the document and choose: Make vector mask. So that the edge doesn't look odd, you could then tweak the path with Direct select tool and possibly blur the edge later on, if it looks too sharp.

Comment: awesome that worked perfectly, thank you very much!